# Install Ubuntu on Mac Mini through a USB pen drive

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I have a Mac Mini with Intel Core Solo processor.

The HD of this computer was formerly part of a PC, and so Windows XP was installed on it. I've successively moved the hard disk from PC to a Mac. All works pretty well, Windows XP starts without any problem. I would now install Ubuntu on this Mac. Alas the DVD drive is out of service, and so I have to find alternatives.

I've thinked to use a pen drive and start installation from this device.
Anyone have experience in this and can tips the best?

Comment: I doubt there will be great trouble. Although considering my setup using a Bluetooth keyboard (it works in EFI Bios) -I wonder if it would work in the boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a ubuntu .iso image from ubuntu.com.

Then you can go to pendrivelinux.com and download the usb installer.

That program will install ubuntu to the usb drive. Once that is done, you have to boot from the usb drive.

You can do this by entering into your bios. I dont know how to do this on a mac, but i know on hp computers, you press f9.

Then once you boot into your usb, it will ask you if you want to install or try ubuntu; Select try ubuntu.

The usb will do it's thing. Then test ubuntu and make sure you like it and all the drivers are working correctly.

Then if you would like to install, click the install icon on the desktop. The steps after are self explanatory. Ubuntu will guide you through the install, and will ask you to reboot after the installation has finished

Thats it, your done. Enjoy ubuntu

Comment: Are you 100% sure this method works? Booting a USB drive on Macs is different from Windows PCs. The key on a Mac is `option`. Which "USB installer" are you talking about, exactly? Can you include a link? Also, the whole procedure is kinda hard to test if you don't have a Mac…

Comment: The only thing that changes in a process what key combination and/or menu to press to boot into the usb AND checking to see if it is hardware compatible

Answer (score -1):

You need iso file of linux distro and burn it to usb key with unetbootin. Than you will probably need to select usb key as first bootable device in BIOS or boot menu whatever mac has.

Comment: -1, not true. With UNetbootin, "The resulting USB drive, however, can be booted on PCs only." – [reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) Also, Macs don't have a BIOS to select boot options.

Answer (score -1):

Blogger is right. You should use Unetbootin to do the trick. http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/files/UNetbootin/575/unetbootin-mac-575.zip/download

You can download the ubuntu iso with unetbootin, or download it by yourself. you select your flashdrive's letter and you're good to go.

Comment: -1, not true. With UNetbootin, "The resulting USB drive, however, can be booted on PCs only." – [reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)